# Bind to a property of a parent element in wpf

Tags: wpf, properties, element, bind, parent

'I want to bind the Height property of the RichTextBox to the Height Property of the GridView`s Row. How can I do that? I do not know how to get the Row's Height as I can not access the Row in xaml what I would like to do.

The Ancestor type should be GridViewHeaderRow , but I do not know its level...

**EDIT:**

```
 <my:RadGridView  Height="524" RowHeight="300" ItemsSource="{Binding Lessons}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Name="dataGrid1" VerticalAlignment="Top" SelectionMode="Single" CanUserSortColumns="False" IsFilteringAllowed="False">

            <my:RadGridView.Columns>
                <my:GridViewDataColumn  DataMemberBinding="{Binding SchoolclassName}" Header="Schoolclass" Width="0.1*" />
                <my:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding SubjectName}"     Header="Subject"      Width="0.1*" />

                <my:GridViewDataColumn  Width="0.3*" Header="Homework">
                    <my:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <RichTextBox Height="{Binding ElementName=dataGrid1,Path=RowHeight}" >
                                <FlowDocument>
                                    <Paragraph>
                                        <Run Text="{Binding Homework}"/>
                                    </Paragraph>
                                </FlowDocument>
                            </RichTextBox>                                
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </my:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>


<my:RadGridView Height="524" ItemsSource="{Binding Lessons}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Name="dataGrid1" VerticalAlignment="Top" SelectionMode="Single" CanUserSortColumns="False" IsFilteringAllowed="False">
            <my:RadGridView.Columns>

                <my:GridViewDataColumn Name="ContentColumn" Width="0.3*" Header="Content">
                    <my:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <RichTextBox Height="{Binding ElementName=MyRowNameToBindTo,Path=Height}">
                                <FlowDocument>
                                    <Paragraph>
                                        <Run Text="{Binding Content}"/>
                                    </Paragraph>
                                </FlowDocument>
                            </RichTextBox>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </my:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
```

...

Answer (score 24):

I don't know about your RadGridView here.  But the first thing I'd try is using a [RelativeSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743599.aspx) Binding with FindAncestor to walk up the visual tree until a GridViewHeaderRow is found and bind to its Height property.

```
 ... Height="{Binding Height, 
              RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, 
                                 AncestorType={x:Type GridViewHeaderRow }}}" ...
```

You may have to walk up the tree to find the RadGridView and then walk back down it to the header row.

```
 ... Height="{Binding HeaderRow.Height, 
              RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, 
                                 AncestorType={x:Type RadGridView }}}" ...
```

or

```
 ... Height="{Binding Rows[0].Height, 
              RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, 
                                 AncestorType={x:Type RadGridView }}}" ...
```

Depends on the implementation of RadGridView.

Comment: I have changed/EDIT the init Question with updated code:

why do I get errors on this: <RichTextBox Height="{Binding ElementName=dataGrid1,Path=RowHeight}" >

I forgot, that RadGridView has a RowHeight property I can bind to via ElementName...

Comment: why do I get this error?

System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'ElementName=dataGrid1'. BindingExpression:Path=RowHeight; DataItem=null; target element is 'RichTextBox' (Name=''); target property is 'Height' (type 'Double')

Comment: ok one more reason to hate teleriks crappy datagrid too.

public double RowHeight {get; set;}

its no dependency property... :S

Comment: It's possible that your RadGridView does not have a NameScope and thus is suffering from the same issue as discussed here - http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2008/07/22/enable-elementname-bindings-with-elementspy/.

Comment: hehe funny I found the same thread yesterday. I do not want to leak reflection into my app ;-)  Well it wouldnt be my job to fix that rather its telerik job to make the RowHeight a dependency property. This I will suggest to them going to be a customer sometimes. If they suck at doing this I will open a blog and do some rants XD

Comment: now hold yourself:

using this in native DataGrid
<RichtTextBox Height="{Binding ElementName=customerDG,Path=RowHeight}" />

works! :P  seems this time MS did their homework although this is exceptional XD