# How to raise a WPF command binded to ListBox item?

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, command

I have a WPF `UserControl` in my Excel add-in project. This control has a `ListBox` and a `StackPanel` with two buttons. `ListBox` consists of items, each of them corresponding to an excel workbook sheet. Also we have two commands to hide/show sheets then `CheckBox`es are checked/uncheked. This part is fine.

The question is how to bind these existing commands to buttons in the stackpanel below. It is necessary that we can multiselect several items in the ListBox then click the button and get the result.

XAML code:

```
<UserControl x:Class="ListsAddin.ListManagementControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="CheckBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">                
                <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding HideSheetCommand}"/>
                </Trigger>

                <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding ShowSheetCommand}"/>
                </Trigger>               
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <StackPanel >
        <ListBox Name="lb" ItemsSource="{Binding lst}" Margin="0,0,0,7" >

            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>    
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Label Content="{Binding Path=SheetName}"/>
                        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsHidden}"
                  Style="{StaticResource CheckBoxStyle}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>

        <StackPanel>
            <Button Content="HideSheet"  Command="{ ?? }"/>
            <Button Content="ShowSheet" Command="{ ?? }" />
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Unless the command is on the item, you'll want to bind to the parent with RelativeSource http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2439593/bind-to-a-property-of-a-parent-element-in-wpf

Comment: Yes, you are right. But how to bind only selected items? Can you provide a code exapmle? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think you can bind only to selected commands, but you can have the command's action only use selected items.