# How to bind an element to a property which belongs to the root element of a control?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, datacontext

The question may sound a little confusing, but the problem I'm currently facing is this:

```xml
<Button x:Class="sandbox.BtnLabel"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
        x:Name="this">
    <Button.ToolTip>
        <TextBlock Background="Yellow" Text="{Binding ElementName=this, Path=LabelText}"/>
    </Button.ToolTip>
    <TextBlock Background="Yellow" Text="{Binding ElementName=this, Path=LabelText}"/>
</Button>
```

Only the second binding works, which sets the content of the button. The first one, which I would like to use to set the contents of the tooltip of the button (via the LabelText dependency property) does not work.

Is it possible to make the first binding work?
Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2439911/1466627).

Comment: Thanks for the reference, but it does not work.
The error I get is:
System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'ElementName=this'. BindingExpression:Path=LabelText; DataItem=null; target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')

Comment: Try with this....  Text={Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type Button}},Path=LabelText}

Comment: Does not work either: System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.Button', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=LabelText; DataItem=null; target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
I tried setting the AncestorType to 'BtnLabel" but the same error appears.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
<Button x:Class="sandbox.BtnLabel"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        x:Name="this">
  <Button.ToolTip>
    <ToolTip DataContext="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
      <TextBlock Background="Yellow"
                 Text="{Binding LabelText}" />
    </ToolTip>
  </Button.ToolTip>
  <TextBlock Background="Yellow"
             Text="{Binding ElementName=this,
                            Path=LabelText}" />
</Button>
```

We add a `ToolTip` element and assign it's `DataContext` as it's `PlacementTarget` which should then reach the `TextBlock`

Comment: Great! That works like I was expecting! I had no idea how 'PlacementTarget' worked. Thanks a lot! (unfortunately I cannot vote up as I don't have enough reputation)